# How to use cookies in Zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework

How I use Zend_Http_Cookie to set and read cookies?

I trie to set cookie like this:

`$cookie = new Zend_Http_Cookie('TestCookie','TestValue','localhost.com')` but no cookie is generated. Also how I read cookies with Zend?

Thanks

Comment: [Zend_Http_Cookie](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.10/_Http_Cookie.html#Zend_Http_Cookie) is a class used for client code (i.e., when writing something that makes a request to another server) - so, no, it won't send a cookie to your browser.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As far as i know is there not "setCookie" Class in Zend Framework. Simply use "plain" php:

```
setcookie('cookieName', 'value', 'lifetime', 'path', 'domain');
```

To read an cookie, you can use `Zend_Controller_Request_Http();` as Example:

```
  $request = new Zend_Controller_Request_Http();
  $myCookie = $request->getCookie('cookieName');
```

Answer (score 4):

For Zend 1.12, there **is** a way to set cookies for the response object.

The link to the portion in the manual is included below.  I've also attached their examples in case the page ever disappears.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.response.html#zend.controller.response.headers.setcookie

```
$this->getResponse()->setRawHeader(new Zend_Http_Header_SetCookie(
    'foo', 'bar', NULL, '/', 'example.com', false, true
));
```

or

```
$cookie = new Zend_Http_Header_SetCookie();
$cookie->setName('foo')
       ->setValue('bar')
       ->setDomain('example.com')
           ->setPath('/')
       ->setHttponly(true);
$this->getResponse()->setRawHeader($cookie);
```

It is important to use Zend's objects and classes so that you don't run into issues when creating Tests ;)

Comment: I was using this method for ages as it seemed to be the way, but I just found out that it is not possible to send multiple cookies this way. Only the last Set-Cookie Raw-Header will get sent to the client as the $replace parameter of the header() call inside Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->sendHeaders() is never set to false with a default of true. Do not use this method with multiple cookies!

Comment: This looks good for ZF 1.12.x:
$this->getResponse()->setHeader('Set-Cookie', $cookie->getFieldValue(), false);

Comment: For Zend-recommended way to set multiple cookies see my response below.

Answer (score 2):

From Zend's github [issue](https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/issues/295) about multiple cookies:

```
$setCookieHeader = new Zend_Http_Header_SetCookie('othername1', 'othervalue1');
$appendCookie = new Zend_Http_Header_SetCookie('othername2', 'othervalue2');
$headerLine = $setCookieHeader->toStringMultipleHeaders(array($appendCookie));

$this->getResponse()->setRawHeader($headerLine);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.cookies.html) for Cookie and remembering from past experience there isn't a way of telling a cookie object to be sent along with a [Response](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.response.html).

I suggest just using `setcookie()`.